# Xcode 11 jumps to every desktop in Mac Os Catalina

Tags: xcode, catalina

I recently updated my macOS Catalina (10.15) and also updated my Xcode to version 11.1 and I'm having issue with the window. Suppose I switch from Desktop-1 to Desktop-2, the Xcode also automatically moves to the current(focused) desktop. 
P.S Only Xcode is showing such kind of behaviour.

Comment: When you right click the icon on the dock, select options and see if it is assigned to all desktops. If you switch it to none, does it solve this issue?

Comment: If this answer worked for you, please accept the answer below so others that have the issue can solve it in the future.

Comment: Yeah, I’ve been waiting for you to write it down :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you right click on the application icon on the dock, you can select Options > and change the "Assign To" from All Desktops to None.